Is this a valid proof that a subset of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is not closed under addition
I am solving the following question from Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:
Q: Show that $ S = \{ T \in \mathcal{L} (V, W) : T \text{ is not injective}$ } is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$
I aimed to show that by either showing that the additive identity doesn't exist in $S$, that $S$ isn't closed under multiplication, or that $S$ isn't closed under addition.
I was able to prove that the additive identity exists in the subset and that it is closed under multiplication, but I am unsure of if my proof that it is not closed under addition (below) is a valid one.
Proof
Let $T, M \in S$, so $\text{null}(T) \neq \{0\}$ and $\text{null}(M) \neq \{0\}$
Let $\text{null}(T) = \{u_1, 0\}$ and $\text{null}(M) = \{u_2, 0\}$, where $u_1, u_2 \in V$ and $u_1 \neq u_2$
$(T+M)(v) = 0$ only if $T(v) = -M(v)$ for all $v$, but $(T+M)(u_1 + u_2) = 0$ only if $T(u_1) = -M(u_2)$, which implies that $u_1 = u_2$, contradicting the fact that $u_1 \neq u_2$ above
Therefore, there is no $v \in V (v \neq 0)$ such that $(T+M)(v) = 0$
$\therefore \text{null}(T+M) = \{0\}$
$\therefore (T+M) \notin S$, so $S$ is not closed under addition
Is it valid to rely on $u_1 \neq u_2$ to make the contradiction even though this is a condition I created myself?

What is the additive identity here? The zero map is injective so it can't be in S!

@Sean: no it isn't! (Unless $\dim V = 0$.)

Okay, at this point there's slightly too much to say to fit into the comments so I'll convert them into an answer.

This is heading in the right direction (you want to show that $S$ is not closed under addition) but your argument as written does not work, for two reasons. First, $T(u_2) = - M(u_1)$ (you have a typo here) does not imply $u_1 = u_2$ (and you can find explicit counterexamples, which I encourage you to try). Second, even if it did, it would not follow that $T + M$ has zero nullspace, because the nullspace might contain some other vector entirely.

In my copy of Axler (3rd edition) this is problem 7 in Exercises 3.B, and it includes the hypothesis that $2 \le \dim V \le \dim W$. This hypothesis is crucial! $S$ actually is a subspace if $\dim V = 1$ or if $\dim V > \dim W$ (this is also a good exercise). This means your argument could not possibly have been correct because you never used this hypothesis.

If you want to understand what's going on here I suggest working out the simplest case, $\dim V = \dim W = 2$, explicitly using $2 \times 2$ matrices. So here the problem is to find two $2 \times 2$ matrices $T, M$ with nontrivial nullspace whose sum has trivial nullspace. Can you do this? If so the next case after this to try is $\dim V = 2, \dim W = 3$, then $\dim V = \dim W = 3$, then $\dim V = 3, \dim W = 4$, and so on until you can see a general pattern.


Your notations $\{ u_1, 0 \}$ and $\{ u_2, 0 \}$ for the nullspaces are also strange; it is not actually possible for the nullspace to only consist of two vectors in this way (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), since it has to be closed under scalar multiplication.

Very nice and clear answer! +1

An additional hint that something is fishy with the problem poster's proof that it 'proves' that every sum of 2 elements of $S$ is suddenly not in $S$. That includes if one summand is the additive identy!

Thank you for your detailed answer. Your 2nd point seems do have done the trick! Using the fact that W's basis has more elements than V's, I was able to find a counterexample to show that $S$ isn't closed under addition. By defining a function T that maps basis vectors $v_i$ to basis vectors $w_i$, the result of $T(v)$ will always be some linear combination of W's basis vectors, which can only equal 0 if all the coefficients are 0 as any part of W's basis is linearly independent. Then summing $T$ with itself or with the identity shows that $S$ isn't closed under addition.

OTOH, if $\text{dim}(V) > \text{dim}(W)$, then any $T$ on $V$ s.t $T$ is not injective will have to produce a linear combination involving each of the $w_i$ basis vectors as well as one repeat $w_j$, thus producing a linearly dependent list as there is now an overlap in the vectors used. If any less basis vectors are produced in the result, $T$ will not satisfy the criterion of being 'not injective', thus if $\text{dim}(V) > \text{dim}(W)$, $S$ is necessarily a subspace. Thanks for highlighting this hypothesis, it definitely helped with my understanding.

@Atiksh: I'm not sure what you're doing but that doesn't look like a complete argument. I can't tell whether the $T$ you've chosen is injective or not (if it's injective it's not in $S$ at all), and either way $T$ is injective iff $T + T$ is, so adding $T$ to itself won't prove anything. Again I encourage you to work through this carefully and explicitly for $2 \times 2$ matrices instead of trying to tackle the full problem for now. Write down, explicitly, two $2 \times 2$ matrices with nontrivial nullspaces whose sum has trivial nullspace; this is not so bad!

@QiaochuYuan: correct me if I'm wrong, but to show that $S$ isn't closed, I just need one example of $T, M \in S$ s.t $T+M \notin S$ right? Let bases of $V, W$ be $v_1, ..., v_m$ and $w_1, ..., w_n$, where $n > m$. Then let $v \in V$ be $a_1v_1 + ... + a_mv_m$. Define $T$ as $T(v_i) = w_i$ except $T(v_1) = 0$, and $M$ as $M(v_i) = w_i$ except $M(v_2) = 0$. $\text{null}(T) = { \lambda v_1, 0}$, same logic for $M$, so both are in $S$. $(T+M)(v) = a_1w_1 + a_2 w_2 + 2a_3 w_3 + ... + 2a_m w_m$, so $(T+M)(v) = 0$ iff $a_1, ..., a_m$ = 0. Therefore $(T+M)(v) = 0$ iff $v = 0$. So $T+M \notin S$.

@Atiksh: yes, that argument works fine! That's not what you wrote above, as far as I can tell. Above you said "summing $T$ with itself or with the identity," neither of which can work, and here you are summing two different linear maps.

@QiaochuYuan: it seems in what I wrote above I did it the wrong way around. Your suggestion to work explicitly with matrices was helpful - I was able to see that I could create a pair of operators like above by taking them each as a matrix with 1 column zeroed out (ie. sending one of the $v_i$ to 0). With a zero column, the operator lets one of the variables in the vector take on any value while still sending the vector to 0, hence making its nullspace nontrivial. However, provided $T, M$'s zero columns are in different positions, the sum may not allow such a free variable.

Then in the case that $\text{dim}(V) > \text{dim}(W)$, similar non-injective operators could be made by zeroing out a column. But the sum of two such operators could never be injective. If the result $T+M$ has a zeroed column, then a variable in the vector could roam free, creating a nontrivial nullspace. But if the result has no zeroed columns, one of the components of the resulting vector $T(v)$ would involve a sum of two or more variables due to the dimensionality reduction. So the nullspace would have vectors where these variables take values s.t these sums equal 0, making it nontrivial.

@Atiksh: yes, that's right. The way I would describe the $\dim V > \dim W$ case is just that every linear map fails to be injective, by the rank-nullity theorem, so $S = L(V, W)$ in this case.
